# How to looping over a column and if pattern matches, count related characters in other columns using R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

0

I have a data frame (picture is attached) with 1000 rows and 21 columns which the first column is miRNA gene names and other columns show each nucleotide in each position: (picture attached)

What I want is to make a loop over the first column and if my character pattern gets matched in the column for example "Ami-Mir-489" (don't consider p1 and p2) then for each position (pos_1, pos_2, ..., pos_20) calculate the frequency of each nucleotide separately.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZim0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the guidance on how to create a minimal, reproducible example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and try to edit your question accordingly. The key part here will be adding data against which to test solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be with the following packages `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `magrittr`.

First you should generate a reproducible example

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Reproducible example
Nucleo <- c("A","T","G","C")
df <- data.frame(gene=paste0("Gene",1:20))
for(x in 1:21){
  df[[paste0("pos_",x)]] <- sample(Nucleo, 20, replace = T)
}
```

Next we will make the dataframe tidy so that we can manipulate it.

```
df <- gather(df, key = "Position", value = "Nucleotide", -gene)

frequency <- df %>%
  group_by(gene, Nucleotide) %>% #specify which groups we will mutate on
  mutate(NucleotitdeCount=n()) %>% #For each gene and Nucleotide type - Count total
  select(gene, Nucleotide, NucleotitdeCount) %>% #Specify Columns we need
  distinct() %>% ungroup() %>% #reduce size to unique instances
  group_by(gene) %>%  #Regroup by gene to mutate over nucleotide counts
  mutate(relativeFreq=NucleotitdeCount/sum(NucleotitdeCount)) #Calculate Relative Frequency
```

I believe it is best to leave the data as it is, but if you want to return it to a long format:

```
freqLong <- frequency %>%
         select(gene, Nucleotide, relativeFreq) %>%
         spread(key = "Nucleotide", value = "relativeFreq")
```

Leaving it in its previous form makes visualization easy with the `ggplot2` package

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(frequency, aes(gene, relativeFreq, fill = Nucleotide)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you do not need to worry about filtering at first.

However if you wish to filter genes first, this can also be done with the dplyr function `filter`

I recommend using it in conjunction with `grepl` for the pattern matching.
this is an example where I match "seto" in the Species column of the data set `iris`

```
iris %>% filter(grepl(pattern = "seto", x = Species)) %>% head()
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Justin thank you for your answer. I tried to run your suggested command lines but I get this error for the frequency script:  Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: Another question since I couldn't run the frequency script, I set my df with filtering and according to my pattern I have 300 genes (these are miRNA families across different species) with the same patterns. With that being said, for total number of 300 genes in my pattern I want to get the percentage of each nucleotide in each position. Is this what the frequency script does?

Comment: @mortezaaslanzadeh , the n() function is usually only called inside these dplyr statements, but it is functionally the same as calculating the length of a vector, if you replace `n()` with `length(Nucleotide)` this code should still run the same. Make sure you get `dplyr` `tidyr` and `magrittr` from cran